# merge sort implementation with linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, mergesort

I am trying to implement merge sort in a linked list in c++. When I execute my code, it runs infinitely no. of time. When I debug it, I found that my mergesort function runs only for the left half infinite number no. of times.I mean it never comes out from left half. That function never called for the right half. I am pasting my whole code link here. Can anyone tell me why the function runs infinitely and what modifications I have to make to my code?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long int
#define mod 1000000007

struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* link;
};
Node* head = NULL;
void ins(int data, int pos)
{
    Node* ptr = new Node();
    ptr->data = data;
    ptr->link = NULL;

    if (pos == 1) {
        ptr->link = head;
        head = ptr;
        return;
    }

    Node* temp = new Node();
    temp = head;
    for (int i = 1; i < pos - 1; i++) {
        temp = temp->link;
    }

    ptr->link = temp->link;
    temp->link = ptr;
    return;
}

Node* getmid(Node* temp)
{
    if (temp == 0) {
        return temp;
    }

    Node* a = temp;
    Node* b = temp;

    while (b->link != 0) {
        b = b->link;
        a = a->link;
        if (b->link != 0) {
            b = b->link;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return a;
}

Node* merge(Node* left, Node* right)
{
    Node* res = NULL;

    if (left == NULL || right == NULL) {
        if (left == NULL) {
            return right;
        }
        if (right == NULL) {
            return left;
        }
        else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    else if ((left->data) < (right->data)) {
        res = left;
        res->link = merge(left->link, right);
    }
    else {
        res = right;
        res->link = merge(left, right->link);
    }

    return res;
}

Node* mergesort(Node* head)
{
    if (head == NULL || (head->link) == NULL) {
        return head;
    }

    Node* mid = getmid(head);
    Node* left = head;
    Node* right = mid->link;
    mid->link = NULL;

    left = mergesort(left);
    right = mergesort(right);

    Node* c = merge(left, right);
    return c;
}

void display()
{
    Node* t = head;

    while (t != 0) {
        cout << t->data << " ";
        t = t->link;
    }
}

int main()
{
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);

    ins(8, 1);
    ins(23, 2);
    ins(73, 3);
    ins(4, 4);
    ins(5, 5);
    ins(7, 6);

    mergesort(head);

    display();
}
```

In the above code, ins function is used to insert the node. getmid function is used for getting the address of the middle node. merge function is used to sort the left and right half. And mergesort function is used to divide the list into 2 half and call each half.display function is used for print linked list

Comment: Anyone any opinion?

Comment: Your function is recursive and will get a call stack as deep as there are nodes. This is weak. It might work sometimes. But when you combine that with the telltale competitive programming `#define mod 1000000007`, you know it's not going to work. Rewrite the merge in a non-recursive fashion.

Comment: @Jeffrey that is not remove my error in code

Comment: Why my code keeps on calling left half again and again?

Comment: Even with Jack Lilhammers fix, the code will run into stack overflow issues for large lists because merge is recursive. Comment: a [bottom up merge sort for linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists) is more efficient. [Example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293656/60310182#60310182) .

Comment: I don't think he'll be using his mergesort in production, with or without my fix :D

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in `getmid()`
For lists of 2 elements it returned the second element, instead of the first.
Therefore with 2 elements **left always pointed to the whole list**, causing an infinite recursion.

```cpp
Node* getmid(Node* temp)
{
    if (temp == nullptr)
        return nullptr;
    if (temp->link == nullptr)
        return temp;

    Node* a = temp;
//---------------------------------
    Node* b = temp->link; // Here!
//---------------------------------

    while (b->link != nullptr) {
        b = b->link;
        a = a->link;

        if (b->link != nullptr)
            b = b->link;
        else
            break;
    }

    return a;
}
```

You can run it here: https://onlinegdb.com/3fhqQyBhy

I'm using `nullptr` instead of `NULL` or `0` and I'm passing the list as a parameter to the insert function

Comment: why u are passing the list as a parameter to the insert function?

Comment: Because to debug your code I tested the different functions one by one and the insert function added elements only to the global list, but I wanted to try with different lists.

Comment: Also, now it's easier to reuse

Comment: @BINDUROY For fun I tested the largest list it could sort OnlineGDB

Comment: Of course keep in mind that large lists will cause stack overflow, as pointed out earlier by @rcgldr

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 
  
/* Link list node */
class Node { 
public: 
    int data; 
    Node* next; 
}; 
  
/* function prototypes */
Node* SortedMerge(Node* a, Node* b); 
void FrontBackSplit(Node* source, 
                    Node** frontRef, Node** backRef); 
  
/* sorts the linked list by changing next pointers (not data) */
void MergeSort(Node** headRef) 
{ 
    Node* head = *headRef; 
    Node* a; 
    Node* b; 
  
    /* Base case -- length 0 or 1 */
    if ((head == NULL) || (head->next == NULL)) { 
        return; 
    } 
  
    /* Split head into 'a' and 'b' sublists */
    FrontBackSplit(head, &a, &b); 
  
    /* Recursively sort the sublists */
    MergeSort(&a); 
    MergeSort(&b); 
  
    /* answer = merge the two sorted lists together */
    *headRef = SortedMerge(a, b); 
} 
  
/* See https:// www.geeksforgeeks.org/?p=3622 for details of this  
function */
Node* SortedMerge(Node* a, Node* b) 
{ 
    Node* result = NULL; 
  
    /* Base cases */
    if (a == NULL) 
        return (b); 
    else if (b == NULL) 
        return (a); 
  
    /* Pick either a or b, and recur */
    if (a->data <= b->data) { 
        result = a; 
        result->next = SortedMerge(a->next, b); 
    } 
    else { 
        result = b; 
        result->next = SortedMerge(a, b->next); 
    } 
    return (result); 
} 
  
/* UTILITY FUNCTIONS */
/* Split the nodes of the given list into front and back halves,  
    and return the two lists using the reference parameters.  
    If the length is odd, the extra node should go in the front list.  
    Uses the fast/slow pointer strategy. */
void FrontBackSplit(Node* source, 
                    Node** frontRef, Node** backRef) 
{ 
    Node* fast; 
    Node* slow; 
    slow = source; 
    fast = source->next; 
  
    /* Advance 'fast' two nodes, and advance 'slow' one node */
    while (fast != NULL) { 
        fast = fast->next; 
        if (fast != NULL) { 
            slow = slow->next; 
            fast = fast->next; 
        } 
    } 
  
    /* 'slow' is before the midpoint in the list, so split it in two  
    at that point. */
    *frontRef = source; 
    *backRef = slow->next; 
    slow->next = NULL; 
} 
  
/* Function to print nodes in a given linked list */
void printList(Node* node) 
{ 
    while (node != NULL) { 
        cout << node->data << " "; 
        node = node->next; 
    } 
} 
  
/* Function to insert a node at the beginging of the linked list */
void push(Node** head_ref, int new_data) 
{ 
    /* allocate node */
    Node* new_node = new Node(); 
  
    /* put in the data */
    new_node->data = new_data; 
  
    /* link the old list off the new node */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref); 
  
    /* move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref) = new_node; 
} 
  
/* Driver program to test above functions*/
int main() 
{ 
    /* Start with the empty list */
    Node* res = NULL; 
    Node* a = NULL; 
  
    /* Let us create a unsorted linked lists to test the functions  
Created lists shall be a: 2->3->20->5->10->15 */
    push(&a, 15); 
    push(&a, 10); 
    push(&a, 5); 
    push(&a, 20); 
    push(&a, 3); 
    push(&a, 2); 
  
    /* Sort the above created Linked List */
    MergeSort(&a); 
  
    cout << "Sorted Linked List is: \n"; 
    printList(a); 
  
    return 0; 
}
```